# Does dm_os_memory_clerks show all SQL Server memory?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

We are running SQL Server 2017 on a machine with 256GB Ram. Noticed a dramatic shift in some performance counters (e.g. page life expectancy usually very high, but had started fluctuating a lot the last few days which prompted this).

Noticed that the buffer pool only seemed to be using ~60GB whereas it was using ~140GB last week.  If I use `sys.dm_os_memory_clerks`

```
SELECT type, SUM (domc.pages_kb) / (1024 * 1024)
FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks AS domc
GROUP BY domc.type
ORDER BY SUM (domc.pages_kb) DESC;
```

It gives out the following

[image]

Which implies SQL Server is only using 65GB of the 230GB it has committed.  Are there some other DMVs that can show the difference and where the rest has gone?

Comment: @ErikDarling  that's the wrong link: https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sql-server/detecting-cache-pressure-with-sp_pressuredetector/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft doh! sorry about that. thanks for the assist.